# Strategy Pattern Implementation

Tags: design-patterns, polymorphism, strategy-pattern

Following is the structure of my class

```
public abstract class BaseUser
{
    protected List<Perm> permissions;
    public abstract void AddPerm(Perm perm);
}

public class NormalUser : BaseUser
{
    public override void AddPerm(Perm perm)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("A normal user cant add permissions");
    }
}

public class SpecialUser : BaseUser
{
    public override void AddPerm(Perm perm)
    {
        if(permissions==null) permissions=new List<Perm>();
            this.permissions.Add(perm);
    }
}

class Container
{
    List<BaseUser> users;
}
```

What is required:

1. Container will keep both types of users
2. SpecialUser will have the functionality of add permissions - Done
3. Normal User will not be allowed add permissions - Done

   I have chosen strategy pattern to achieve above

   The thing I am not able to achieve is
4. Both Types of users will be hydrated from the Database (The users will be initialized with list of default permissions)

Am I right in choosing this pattern in this situation? If yes then how do I address requirement 4?

Many Thanks,
asolvent

Comment: I can't see a strategy pattern here. You just derive two classes from a common base class. Your question seem to be about data access, so you have at least to specify what kind of technology you use to access the database and show some related code.
Regarding to your AddPerm method: I would not declare it in the base class but only in the SpecialUser class. So its clear that a client can't call it on a user of type NormalUser.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I call it Strategy because either a User will be Special or Normal. The Container has a List of users (Special + Normal). I might be wrong but isn't that how we implement a strategy? ( I am no expert at it, please guide if my interpretation is incorrect)

If I decide to put the method in child class then I would not be able to call it via parent and eventually I will end up in having 2 different collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example your provided is not really an instance of the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), it is just a method override. The strategy pattern involves a context object and a strategy object. Regardless, I would try to avoid the temptation to apply OOP in all possible places. Instead of inheritance consider using a UserType enum and a simple if statement to support the required behavior. This makes it easier to map to a database and also keeps the code simple:

```
enum UserType {
 Normal,
 Special
}

class User {

public UserType Type { get; set; }  

public override void AddPerm(Perm perm){
  switch (this.Type) {
 // logic goes here
  } 
 }
}
```

This type of problem is a recurring theme in using OOP in enterprise data driven applications and I normally try to keep things as simple as possible. Do you really need to derive a base User type to provide the required functionality? Will it have additional behaviors and properties?

Comment: The original code violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and this code reverses the [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) refactoring. I'm not sure which I like least.

Comment: The original code only violates LSP if the contract for the AddPerm method did not specify that an exception can be thrown. Ultimately, the decision is context dependent - patterns and principles can provide a basis for a solution, not a solution itself. Given typical considerations of a user system, I believe the reversal of the refactoring seems fitting.

Comment: True, It Depends. The refactoring reversal can also work when a functional style is warranted. I don't think we have enough information to definitively answer this question, though.